# How to display the full figure with Plot function?

Tags: plotting

I met a simple problem. I want to plot the figure of the function $r^{1/10}$ in the interval $[0,0.1]$. Obviously, the value of the function tends to zero as $r\rightarrow 0$. However, when I plot this function with `Plot`, it shows the following figure:

[image]

The problem is that, as is displayed in the figure, the value of the function does not tends to zero. 
My command is

```
Plot[r^(1/10), {r, 0, 0.1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{x, x^.1}, {x, 0, .1}, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Plot[Power[r, (10)^-1], {r, 0, .1} , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotPoints -> {Automatic, {0}}]
```

[image]

Option `PlotPoints-> {Automatic, {0}}` tells MMA to include value `{0}`

Comment: It works! Thank you!